# python 3 reading autherticated webpage after fully loaded

Tags: python

I am struggling to find a way to read data from a webpage (URL in code) after it has fully loaded and after logging onto a website (LOGIN_URL in code). Currently the print statement in my code shows the data from the webpage whilst it is still loading; how can I get the data after the web page has finished loading?

Code:

```
    login_url='LOGIN_URL'
    s=requests.session()
    username = input("Please enter your username: ")
    password=getpass.getpass("Please enter your password: ")
    data={"username" : username,"password" :password}
    content=s.post(login_url,data=data)
    url='PAGE_TO_NAVIGATE_TO_AFTER_LOGIN' 
    data = s.get(url)
    time.sleep(10)
    print(data.text)
```

Any suggestions/help would be greatly appreciated - I am fairly new to Python (3).

Comment: What do you mean by "fully loaded"?  I am sure that your print happens after the page is in fact fully loaded, but your program is not a complete web browser and so your program does not retrieve the other resources (CSS, images, scripts) referenced by the page nor does it implement any of the dynamic behavior (namely javascript execution) that a web browser performs.

Comment: The web page that is retrieved will have a message stating that it is still loading the data - I want to save the webpage after all of the content has been loaded. So how would I get all the other resources from the webpage?

Comment: The short answer is to implement the entire set of specifications ... you would need to parse the HTML and process it ... you would need to create an entire web browser.  You would be better served by taking an entirely different approach and use selenium to drive an existing browser as Max Paymar suggested in his answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably need to use a webdriver. It's software that acts like a browser, and you can use it to navigate through web pages like a normal user would. I have used [selenium's expected conditions](http://www.seleniumhq.org/docs/04_webdriver_advanced.jsp) to solve your problem before. You can tell selenium to wait until a certain element is loaded to get the html. So you will need to find an element that is present only when the page is finished loading manually by using your browser's developer tools. Once you find it you can tell selenium to wait for that element.

Comment: Okay. Thanks for the link I will have a read and see whether using a webdriver resolves my issues.

Comment: Doesn't look like I will be able to use this solution as I am unable to modify my system paths without going through IT. Any other suggestions?

Comment: As @dsh said your python script is not a browser so doing a simple request will not execute the javascript on the page. You will need some kind of web driver or headless browser to solve this. I'm sure IT would be happy to help you if you explained why you need the dependency. There's no harm in asking.

Comment: Can you use virtualenv https://virtualenv.pypa.io/en/stable/ to avoid installing dependencies in the system python?

Comment: Thanks All - and apologies for the delay. I only got back to this yesterday and the webdriver did resolve this issue so thanks Max!